# OnFlush not working Symfony2 ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Hi I want to create Logs who did what in my Bundle. So I am using OnFlush Event of Symfony2. and created a Listener for this. but it is not triggered.

**//My Listener**

```
namespace Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Edu\AccountBundle\CommonFunctions\CommonFunctions;
use Edu\AccountBundle\Constants\allConstants;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ODM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class OnFlushListener
{
    private $session;
    private $router;
    private $commonFunctions;
    private $constants;

    public function __construct(Session $session, Router $router, DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->dm = $dm;
        $this->commonFunctions  = new CommonFunctions();
        $this->constants        = new allConstants();
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        echo "come here after Saving data";die;
    }
}
```

**//config.xml**

```
<service id="edu.account.event.listener" class="Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\OnFlushListener">
    <argument type="service" id="session"/>
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager"/>
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event = "onFlush" method="onFlush"/>
</service>
```

While I am trying to save any document it is not get called. the "onFlush" method. Please guide what i am missing in this.

Thanks Advance

Comment: Please try 'exit(dump("come here after Saving data"))'.

Comment: Still not working. it seems control does not goes there

Comment: Where is your config.xml file ? Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: Have you updated all your entities managed by doctrine before ?

Comment: I am using MongoDB Not MySql. So it is ODM. I did not updated my documents before

Comment: My config.xml is inside my bundle:  Edu/AccountBundle/Resources/config.

config.xml
<service id="edu.account.event.listener" class="Edu\AccountBundle\EventListener\OnFlushListener">
    <argument type="service" id="session"/>
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager"/>
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event = "onFlush" method="onFlush"/>
</service>

Comment: Cache Also cleared. but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service tag's name is wrong, it should be `doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_listener`. Please see [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#registering-event-listeners-and-subscribers) for more details.

Comment: Giving this Error Now:
ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager", path: "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_manager -> edu.account.event.listener".

Comment: Don't inject `DocumentManager` into your service, you'll be able to get one from the `Event` that is passed to your method

Comment: how will I get the Doucment name inside my method. without mongoConnection then. Please guide I am using it first time..

Comment: I did not get any document for Symfony+ODM (mongo) insted there are so many documents for Symfoy+ORM (mysql). I want to create Logs on Add/Update/Delete

Comment: You'll be better suited by `prePersist`, `preUpdate` and `preRemove` (or their `post` counterparts, design decision is up to you) as these events are fired on per-document basis